# Why do I still have to use BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK or BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK on linux when compiling with boost?

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, linker

AFAIK, these two macros are used to enable auto_link.hpp to generate #pragma comment(lib, name) so that the linker can automatically link the used libraries, which should only works on windows. But on linux, why do I still need to define at least one of the two macros, while the used libraries must also be specified? Or how do these two macros work on linux?

Answer (score 1):

The macros:

- BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK
- BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
- BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
- etc

indicate that the code will be linked against a dynamically loaded (`so` or `dll`) `boost` library.

Since `boost` libraries on `linux` are normally built as dynamically loaded libraries it is necessary to define one of the macros above to link the relevant `boost` libraries.

`Boost` libraries on `Windows` are normally built as statically linked libraries.
However, if the relevant `boost` libraries have been built as dynamically loaded libraries then the macros are also required when building on `Windows`.

Comment: This does not seem to answer my question. Yes, I know that these macros are used for dynamic linking, more precisely, for auto-linking, which let me not to manually specify the linked libraries and which is not supported by gcc. So I wonder why I still need to define one of them on linux. Shouldn't the link be made after I manually specify those used libraries?

Comment: AFIK the macros have nothing to do with auto link, their purpose is to link against dynamically loaded libraries as described. Auto linking can be disabled by defining the macro `BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` .

Comment: What I can see is that BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB does control the main switch of the auto link, but it can't be said that BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK has nothing to do with auto link(It causes BOOST_DYN_LINK to be defined, thus affecting auto link). In addition to this part, BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK seems to only affect BOOST_LOG_API, which in turn affects BOOST_SYMBOL_IMPORT. But for clang/gcc on linux, BOOST_SYMBOL_IMPORT will finally be defined as empty, so how does BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK affect the linking process?

Comment: @ArvinHsu the title of your question is about `*DYN_LINK` macros on linux, which I have answered. AFIK `auto link` is unrelated and only works with the MSVC and Borland Windows compilers. If you want to know more about auto link then I recommend that you ask a new question.